# Retrieve identical values in each field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know if it is possible to only highlight from the table below the rows whose values are in all the columns

The table `test_table`:

| a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

What I am looking for is that only the values 5 and 6 are found in all columns a1, a2, a3 and a4, so I want the result:

| a |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 6 |

Is there a simple way to write this in SQL?

Thank for your help
(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Does your example result mean "row 5" (3,0,0,0) and "row 6" (1,0,0,0)? Why do you not want row 7 then, as it contains row 5's values just in different fields? Or does the example result mean that values `5` and `6` occur at least once in each column (they don't, as `5` is missing from column `a2` and `6` is missing from `a4`)? Can you clarify what that `5` and `6` mean in your desired result and why?

Comment: I want to retrieve the values found at least once in each column. finally it will be the value 6 which will be the result, 5 it is not present in a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way to do that is to search each column of your table separately and select only the first column, like this(I'm not sure if you want zero("0") values):

```
select distinct a.a1 from test_table a where exists(select * from test_table aa where aa.a2=a.a1)
and exists(select * from test_table aaa where aaa.a3=a.a1)
and exists(select * from test_table aaaa where aaaa.a4=a.a1) and a.a1<>0
```